# Is there a way to control line height for multiline text drawn by Quartz in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, quartz-graphics, multiline

I am using Quartz for cell rendering in my table views. It works nice, but to meet design concept I must somehow find the way to adjust line heights of the multiline text.
At the moment I am using convenient UIKit additions to NSString to render the text:

```
– drawInRect:withFont:lineBreakMode:alignment:
```

However, I can not find anywhere it the documentation the way to set up line spacing.
UIWebView is capable of that so it must use some lower level API to calculate line-height CSS property.
Can you recommend the solution compatible with iOS 3.0, 3.1? 
I know I could try to use Core Text but it is available from the iOS 3.2.

Comment: Do you really want to keep compatibility with iOS 3? The only people who aren't upgrading are ones who probably never use the app store (or connect their devices to their desktop machines).

Comment: That is interesting point and I thought of that. But isn't it possible there are also the people with iPhone 3G but do not update to iOS4 for performance reasons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the short answer here is no.  I've worked with this problem for a while, and had to eventually implement my own solution for a label.  I'll post this solution below.  Hopefully it's helpful in implementing something yourself.  Excuse the length and number of files, I broke it down for testability, and it handles ellipsizing as well.

```
//MHLabel.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MHTextRuler.h"

@interface MHLabel : UIView<MHTextRuler> {
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *text;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIFont *font;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIColor *textColor;
@property (nonatomic) UITextAlignment textAlignment;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat lineSpacingMuliplier;
@property (nonatomic) int maxLines;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) int currentLines;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL ellipsized;

- (CGFloat) constrainHeightForCurrentWidth;

@end


//MHLabel.m
#import "MHLabel.h"
#import "UILabel+MH.h"
#import "MHUI.h"
#import "MHLabelLines.h"
#import "MHLabelLayout.h"

@interface MHLabel() 

- (MHLabelLines *) linesForWidth: (CGFloat) width;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *lineCache;

@end

@implementation MHLabel

@synthesize text = _text;
@synthesize font = _font;
@synthesize textColor = _textColor;
@synthesize textAlignment = _textAlignment;
@synthesize lineSpacingMuliplier = _lineSpacingMuliplier;
@synthesize maxLines = _maxLines;
@synthesize lineCache = _lineCache;

- (id) initWithFrame: (CGRect) frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame: frame])) {
        self.opaque = NO;
        self.maxLines = 0;
        self.lineSpacingMuliplier = 1;
        self.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        self.font = [MHUI fontOfSize: 16];
        self.textColor = [MHUI darkGrayText];
        self.lineCache = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        self.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTopLeft;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc {
    self.text = nil;
    self.font = nil;
    self.textColor = nil;
    self.lineCache = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void) setFrame: (CGRect) frame {
    [super setFrame: frame];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void) setText: (NSString *) text {
    if (![text isEqualToString: _text]) {
        [_text release];
        _text = [text copy];
        [self.lineCache removeAllObjects];
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}

- (void) setFont: (UIFont *) font {
    if (![font isEqual: _font]) {
        [_font release];
        _font = font;
        [_font retain];
        [self.lineCache removeAllObjects];
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}

- (void) setMaxLines: (NSInteger) maxLines {
    if (maxLines != _maxLines) {
        _maxLines = maxLines;
        [self.lineCache removeAllObjects];
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}

- (void) setTextColor: (UIColor *) textColor {
    if (![textColor isEqual: _textColor]) {
        [_textColor release];
        _textColor = textColor;
        [_textColor retain];
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}

- (void) setLineSpacingMuliplier: (CGFloat) lineSpacingMuliplier {
    if (lineSpacingMuliplier != _lineSpacingMuliplier) {
        _lineSpacingMuliplier = lineSpacingMuliplier;
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}

- (MHLabelLines *) linesForWidth: (CGFloat) width {
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"w%d", (int) width];
    if (![self.lineCache objectForKey: key]) {
        MHLabelLines *labelLines = [MHLabelLayout linesForText: self.text constrainedToLines: self.maxLines andWidth: width withRuler: self];
        [self.lineCache setObject: labelLines forKey: key];
    }
    return [self.lineCache objectForKey: key];
}

- (CGFloat) constrainHeightForCurrentWidth {
    CGSize size = [self sizeThatFits: CGSizeMake(self.bounds.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
    CGRect newFrame = self.frame;
    newFrame.size = size;
    self.frame = newFrame;
    return size.height;
}

- (CGSize) sizeThatFits: (CGSize) size {
    CGFloat width = size.width;
    NSArray *lines = [self linesForWidth: width].lines;
    CGFloat textHeight = [@"X" sizeWithFont: self.font].height;
    CGFloat height = floorf(textHeight * self.lineSpacingMuliplier) * [lines count];
    return CGSizeMake(width, height);
}

- (void) drawRect: (CGRect) rect {
    CGFloat width = rect.size.width;
    NSArray *lines = [self linesForWidth: width].lines;
    CGFloat y = 0;
    CGFloat textHeight = [@"X" sizeWithFont: self.font].height;
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [self.textColor CGColor]);
    for (NSString *string in lines) {
        CGFloat x;
        if (self.textAlignment == UITextAlignmentLeft) {
            x = 0;
        } else {
            CGFloat textWidth = [string sizeWithFont: self.font].width;
            if (self.textAlignment == UITextAlignmentCenter) {
                x = MAX(0, roundf((width - textWidth) / 2));
            } else {
                x = MAX(0, width - textWidth);
            }
        }
        [string drawAtPoint: CGPointMake(x, y) forWidth: width withFont: self.font lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeMiddleTruncation];
        y = floorf(y + (textHeight * self.lineSpacingMuliplier));
    }
}

- (int) currentLines {
    return [[self linesForWidth: self.bounds.size.width].lines count];
}

- (BOOL) ellipsized {
    return [self linesForWidth: self.bounds.size.width].ellipsized;
}

- (CGFloat) widthForText: (NSString *) text {
    return [text sizeWithFont: self.font].width;
}

@end

//MHLabelLines.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MHLabelLines : NSObject {
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *lines;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL ellipsized;

@end

//MHLabelLines.m
#import "MHLabelLines.h"

@implementation MHLabelLines

@synthesize lines = _lines;
@synthesize ellipsized = _ellipsized;

- (void) dealloc {
    self.lines = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

@end

//MHLabelLayout.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MHLabelLines.h"
#import "MHTextRuler.h"

@interface MHLabelLayout : NSObject {
}

+ (MHLabelLines *) linesForText: (NSString *) text constrainedToLines: (int) maxLines andWidth: (CGFloat) width withRuler: (id<MHTextRuler>) ruler;

@end

//MHLabelLayout.m
#import "MHLabelLayout.h"

@interface MHLabelLayout()

+ (int) lastIndexForString: (NSString *) string thatFits: (CGFloat) width withRuler: (id<MHTextRuler>) ruler; 

@end

@implementation MHLabelLayout

+ (MHLabelLines *) linesForText: (NSString *) text constrainedToLines: (int) maxLines andWidth: (CGFloat) width withRuler: (id<MHTextRuler>) ruler {
    MHLabelLines *labelLines = [[[MHLabelLines alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSMutableArray *lines = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSString *remainingText = text;
    while ([remainingText length] > 0 && (maxLines == 0 || [lines count] < maxLines)) {
        int nextLineLastIndex = [self lastIndexForString: remainingText thatFits: width withRuler: ruler];
        NSString *nextString = [remainingText substringToIndex: nextLineLastIndex];
        remainingText = [remainingText substringFromIndex: MIN(nextLineLastIndex + 1, [remainingText length])];
        if ([lines count] + 1 == maxLines && [remainingText length]) {
            labelLines.ellipsized = YES;
            nextString = [nextString stringByAppendingString: @"..."];
            int ellipsizedIndex = [self lastIndexForString: nextString thatFits: width withRuler: ruler];
            while (ellipsizedIndex + 1 < [nextString length]) {
                nextString = [[nextString substringToIndex: ellipsizedIndex] stringByAppendingString: @"..."];
                ellipsizedIndex = [self lastIndexForString: nextString thatFits: width withRuler: ruler];
            }
        }
        [lines addObject: nextString];
    }
    labelLines.lines = lines;
    return labelLines;
}

+ (int) lastIndexForString: (NSString *) string thatFits: (CGFloat) width withRuler: (id<MHTextRuler>) ruler {
    int index = 0;
    int nextIndex = 0;
    int stringLength = [string length];
    while (index < stringLength) {
        nextIndex = index + 1;
        NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(nextIndex, stringLength - nextIndex);
        NSRange foundRange = [string rangeOfString: @" " options: NSLiteralSearch range: searchRange];
        if (foundRange.location == NSNotFound) {
            nextIndex = stringLength;
        } else {
            nextIndex = foundRange.location;
        }

        CGFloat nextStringWidth = [ruler widthForText: [string substringToIndex: nextIndex]];
        if (nextStringWidth > width) {
            if (index == 0) {
                index = nextIndex;
            }
            break;
        } else {
            index = nextIndex;
        }
    }

    NSRange newlineRange = [string rangeOfString: @"\n" options: NSLiteralSearch range: NSMakeRange(0, index)];
    if (newlineRange.location != NSNotFound) {
        index = newlineRange.location;
    }
    return index;
}


@end

//MHTextRuler.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol MHTextRuler <NSObject>

- (CGFloat) widthForText: (NSString *) text;

@end
```